# Zimbra Still Receiving Email After MX Change

Tags: email, gmail, mx-record, zimbra, incoming-mail

Over 24 hours ago, our server admin added the MX records for our Gmail Business Account to our DNS zone.  He set them as follows (6th record hidden for security):

```
Priority    Points to
1   ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5   ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5   ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10  ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10  ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
20  GW.---Zimbra Server-----.COM.
```

When someone is logged into **Gmail** and sends an email to someone else in our company, the email arrives in their **Gmail** account.  **However**, when someone is logged into their **Zimbra** email and sends one to the same email address as before, it's arrives in that person's **Zimbra** account.

I am not well versed in MX records, but it was my understanding that when an email is sent, it attempts to send to the first server in the list and if it fails, it just keeps trying down the list until it succeeds.  But that doesn't seem to be the case in our instance.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Zimbra checks locale settings (LDAP) before MX records. You will have to set up your domain in Split Domain mode to achieve what you want. More about this here: http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Split_Domain